# Pandas: merge both DataFrames using an inner join; only the column name common to both and two others

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes as follow:

```
df_user_usage:
outgoing_mins_per_month     outgoing_sms_per_month  monthly_mb  use_id
0                             21.97     4.82    1557.33     22787
1                            1710.08    136.88  7267.55     22788
2                            1710.08    136.88  7267.55     22789
3                              94.46    35.17   519.12          22790
4                              71.59    79.26   1557.33     22792

df_user_device:
use_id  user_id     platform    platform_version    device  use_type_id
0   22782             26980         ios10.2            iPhone7,2    2
1   22783             29628        android6.0            Nexus 5    3
2   22784             28473        android5.1            SM-G903F   1
3   22785             15200         ios10.2             iPhone7,2   3
4   22786             28239        android6.0            ONE E1003  1
```

I want to merge both `DataFrame` using an inner join, but I don't require all the columns from `df_user_device`; only the column name common to both and two others 'platform' and 'device'. How can I do that?

I have tried this:

pd.merge(df_user_usage,df_user_device, how='inner').head()

but I want to show only the 'platform' and 'device' from df_user_device.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please format your question. Eventually have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Use `left_on`/`right_on` with lists of the column names (in the same order)